# Multiple Dynamic Views from same server

Tags: model-view-controller

We have a requirement to generate multiple dynamic views out of same server. We have java based application which is deployed on Tomcat. Now we want to create view layer. View should get generated based on the device. Example, for PC users,view generates Flash/Flex contents, for iPhone users, it generates HTML content, for Roku users it generates BrightScript contents etc.

Can someone suggest any MVC(or any other) framework which helps us generate multiple views out of the same model.  If not any framework, what could be the strategy to generate different output from the same server application.

Answer (score 0):

You should have 3 different clients and one type of DATA, during start you have to init clients using server's data. You shouldn't generate clients because it is bad idea just init clients.! And the one of the principals  mvc  is common data and different views.

Comment: Thanks for this information. So I can instantiate the client based on some parameter(say device name). Now the question is do we have any generic single framework, I can use to generate different output like html/flex etc. from the same generic model.For example, Struts framework allows tp generate html output. Can we have something similar single framework which allows us to generate different output formats.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some different links like mydemo.com/pc mydemo.com/iph and so on. Server will be one but clients will be differents.